# React Markdown type for paragraph renderer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, markdown, react-markdown

I could not find anything, neither on GitHub nor *index.d.ts* of the package *react.markdown*. It looks like a very simple example, yet the entire Google does not contain any example. I wrote a custom renderer for a Markdown component, but I could not figure out the type for the renderer:

```
import ReactMarkdown, { Renderers, Renderer, NodeType } from "react-markdown";

const PostContent: React.FC<PostContent> = ({ blog }) => {
  const customRenderers: Renderers = {
    paragraph(paragraph) {
      const { node } = paragraph;
      if (node.children[0].type === "image") {
        const image = node.children[0];
        return (
          <div style={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: "60rem" }}>
            <Image
              src={`/images/posts/${blog.slug}/${image.src}`}
              alt={image.alt}
              width={600}
              height={300}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    },
  };

  return (
    <article className="">
      <ReactMarkdown renderers={customRenderers}>{blog.content}</ReactMarkdown>
    </article>
  );
};
```

What is the type of paragraph? I checked; it is Renderer:

```
   type Renderer<T> = (props: T) => ElementType<T>
```

I could not figure out what to pass as T. I tried, HtmlParagraphElement or any.

Comment: The types define the props of `paragraph` as `any`.  I'm not sure what they actually are.  You will get rid of all TS errors if you type `customRenderers` as `{[nodeType: string]: ElementType}` which is the type of the `renderers` prop.  I've got to play with this to figure out what the `any` actually is!

Comment: I thought we could make use of the types from the underlying markdown package but react-markdown renames some of the props! https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/blob/236182ecf30bd89c1e5a7652acaf8d0bf81e6170/src/ast-to-react.js#L70

Comment: @LindaPaiste my brain is about to burn. What is this?  it is not an npm package, and react-markdown installed module has no src.

Comment: These are the types for react-markdown: https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/blob/236182ecf30bd89c1e5a7652acaf8d0bf81e6170/index.d.ts  There's not much there.  There is nothing there that tells you what props a `paragraph` element gets called with.  But you can see that the types for a node rely on an imported type `mdast.Content`  Those `mdast` types include all of the possible node and the node properties. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mdast/index.d.ts So we can make use of mdast types to get strict typing for `paragraph.node` (cont.)

Comment: Using some TS magic here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-markdown-typescript-yi7ij?file=/src/App.tsx I got the `customRenderers` map to recognize all of the properties that are present on the `node` (`props.node`) based on the key name (`paragraph`, `image`, etc.).  This should work and you get typed access to everything in its "raw" form.

Comment: However there are other properties that are added to `props` by the react-markdown package which do not have typescript definitions anywhere.  What's happening in the source code file that I linked is their mapping of properties on the `node` to custom top-level properties.  For example an `image` gets called with `props` that include `props.node` which has properties `{ type, title, url, alt, position }` -- the stuff that we know based on the mdast types -- but it also gets `props.src`, `props.alt`, and  `props.title`, which are the untyped, unndocumented top-level props.

Comment: @LindaPaiste you could write those as an answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Renderer Type

The react-markdown package is very loosely typed.  It [declares](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/blob/236182ecf30bd89c1e5a7652acaf8d0bf81e6170/index.d.ts#L45) the type of `renderers` as an object map

```
{[nodeType: string]: ElementType}
```

where the keys can be any `string` (not just valid node types) and the values have the type `ElementType` imported from the [React typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5dfa1a2690017d1d4eedf251548145661fa2c1e8/types/react/index.d.ts#L69).  `ElementType` means that your renderer can be a built-in element tag name like `"p"` or `"div"` or a function component or class component that takes `any` props.

You could just type your object as

```
const customRenderers: {[nodeType: string]: ElementType} = { ...
```

#### Typing the Props

`ElementType`  is not at all useful for getting type safety inside the render function.  The type says the the `props` can be anything.  It would be nice if we could know what `props` our render function is actually going to be called with.

Our `paragraph` gets called with props `node` and `children`.  A `code` element gets called with props `language`, `value`, `node` and `children`.  The custom props like the  `language` and `value` are unfortunately not documented in Typescript anywhere.  You can [see them being set](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/blob/236182ecf30bd89c1e5a7652acaf8d0bf81e6170/src/ast-to-react.js#L44) in the `getNodeProps` function of the react-markdown source code. There are different props for each node type.

#### Typing the Node

The props `node` and `children` are where we can actually get useful Typescript information.

The react-markdown types [show](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/blob/236182ecf30bd89c1e5a7652acaf8d0bf81e6170/index.d.ts#L37) that the type for a `node` is the `Content` type imported from the underlying markdown parser package mdast.  [This `Content` type](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5dfa1a2690017d1d4eedf251548145661fa2c1e8/types/mdast/index.d.ts#L13) is the union of all individual markdown node types.  These individual types all have a distinct `type` property which a `string` literal that matches the key that we want to set on our `renderers` object!

So finally we know that the type for valid keys is `Content["type"]`.  We also know that the `node` prop for a specific `K` key will be `Extract<Content, { type: K }>` which gives us the member of the union that matches this `type` property.

The `children` prop on the `props` object is just a typical React children prop, but not all node types have children.  We we can know whether or not our `props` include `children` by looking at the type for the `node` and seeing whether or not it has a `children` property.

```
type NodeToProps<T> = {
  node: T;
  children: T extends { children: any } ? ReactNode : never;
};
```

(this matches the received props because the `children` prop is always set, but will be `undefined` if children are not supported)

So now we can define a strict type for your `customRenderers` -- or any custom renderer map:

```
type CustomRenderers = {
  [K in Content["type"]]?: (
    props: NodeToProps<Extract<Content, { type: K }>>
  ) => ReactElement;
};
```

#### Conditional Overriding

Your code will intercept all `paragraph` nodes, but will only return any content when the condition `node.children[0].type === "image"` is met.  That means all other paragraphs get removed!  You need to make sure that you *always* return something.

```
const PostContent: React.FC<PostContent> = ({ blog }) => {
  const customRenderers: CustomRenderers = {
    // node has type mdast.Paragraph, children is React.ReactNode
    paragraph: ({ node, children }) => {
      if (node.children[0].type === "image") {
        const image = node.children[0]; // type mdast.Image
        return (
          <div
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              maxWidth: "60rem"
            }}
          >
            <img
              src={`/images/posts/${blog.slug}/${image.src}`}
              alt={image.alt}
              width={600}
              height={300}
            />
          </div>
        );
      } 
      // return a standard paragraph in all other cases
      else return <p>{children}</p>;
    },
  };

  return (
    <article className="">
      <ReactMarkdown renderers={customRenderers}>{blog.content}</ReactMarkdown>
    </article>
  );
};
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-markdown-typescript-yi7ij?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Hi Linda. I am having issue here  ` const { language, value } = code;`. it says "Property 'language' does not exist on type 'NodeToProps<Code>'"

Comment: Right so you are trying to access the custom properties that are hard to type so I haven't included them.  With this type definition you would need to do `const {node} = code;  const {lang, value} = node;`  I think `value` should be there? I know it's `lang` and not `language` on the `node`.

Comment: This will be last issue. Thank you for your help so far. <ReactMarkdown renderers={customRenderers}>       renderers does not accept type CustomRenderers. gives me this error.

Comment: "Type 'CustomRenderers' is not assignable to type '{ [nodeType: string]: ElementType<any>; }'.
  Property 'paragraph' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '((props: NodeToProps<Paragraph>) => ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, any> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ElementType<any>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ElementType<any>'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(45, 14): The expected type comes from property 'renderers' which is declared here on type '(IntrinsicAttributes & ....

Comment: Your renderer always has to return something in order to be a valid react component.  If you want to display nothing then return null.  But you cannot use the custom render only in certain situations.  If you don’t return anything then then node won’t show up at all.

Comment: renderer returns component in both cases. I currently solved the issue with this, renderers={customRenderers as any}. thank you for your help

Comment: The error message *Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ElementType<any>'* implies that there is a missing return somewhere.  Like an `if` that's missing an `else`.  If you post it a typescript playground or codesandbox I can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change 'renderer' to 'components':

```
<ReactMarkdown components={customRenderers}>{blog.content}</ReactMarkdown>
```